# x and y must be the same sizeのエラーについて

Tags: python

csvファイルを読み込んで散布図でプロットしたいのですが、次のようになります。

```
>>> dcount=[j for i in range(14) for j in range(44)]
>>> pyplot.scatter(dcount,data['average'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/takumi/Ureka/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3200, in scatter
linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts, **kwargs)
  File "/home/takumi/Ureka/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3592, in scatter
    raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

何が問題か教えていただきたいです。お願いします！

Answer (score 2):

`scatter`に与える引数は、同じ長さでなければいけません。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# OK
plt.scatter([0, 1, 10, 100], [0, 1, 2, 3])

# ValueError: x and y must be the same size
plt.scatter([0, 1, 10, 100], [0, 1])
```